# Matplotlib share axes with plyplot.subplot() command?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been wondering this forever: How can I set graphs in Matplotlib to share axes when I use the plt.subplot(221) (for example) command? Rather than saying:

```
fig, axes = plt.suplots(2,2,sharex=True, sharey=True)
```

I would like to say:

```
plt.subplot(221, sharex=True, sharey=True)
```

So that I don't have to deal with this annoying array that plt.subplots returns, but obviously this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tuple unpacking to avoid creating the `axes` array:

```
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.suplots(2, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
```

Afterwards you can plot as usual.

e.g. `ax2.plot(...)` will then plot to the top right subplot.

Comment: I am not sure, I don't know a way. However in my opinion the `subplots` command results in much cleaner code. If you have so many subplots that the tuple unpacking becomes unreadable, I find  `axes[2,2].plot(...)` nicer than `plt.subplot(221, sharex=True, sharey=True)`